Integral of a function using given integration of complemetary function
So, I was wondering, if we assume that we know:
$\int_{x=0}^{x = 2\pi} \cos(x) f(x)$ = $\alpha$, where $f(x)$ is a continuous, differentiable function in x $\in [0,2\pi]$, and $\alpha$ is the evaluated integral.
Can we calculate:
$\int_{x=0}^{x = 2\pi} \sin(x) f(x)$? without knowing exact form of $f(x)$?
I tried using integration by parts, or substituting $y = \pi/2 - x$, to evaluate above integral in some functional form of $\alpha$, but failed!
Any help/directions will be appreciated. If you wish, you can think of this problem in backwards: knowing $\int_{x=0}^{x = 2\pi} \sin(x) f(x)$ and evaluating $\int_{x=0}^{x = 2\pi} \cos(x) f(x)$

Without knowing anything about $f(x)$ other than what $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x)f(x)dx$ is , you can't know what $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)f(x)dx$.

Intuitively, the given equation only gives one value of the ($\cos,\sin$ form) Fourier series of $f$, so the answer is no.

Thank you everyone for your response. Just wanted to know whether the problem is solvable or not.

Of course not. Consider $f_n(x)=f(x)+n\sin{(x)}$. Then the integral of $\cos{(x)}f_n(x)$ is equal to the integral of $\cos{(x)}f(x)$. But the integral of $\sin{(x)}f_n(x)$ changes with n.
